# Linux: list all available window managers

Tags: linux, window-managers

How do I get a list of all available windows managers on a linux system (Of course this would mostly not be needed but - I don't have root permissions).
  Very difficult to search on Google as all results returned are for "list of window managers for linux".

Clarification:  I am looking for a command that lists "All window managers that are installed" on the system that I am working on.

Interested to know it's distro dependent. My distro is RedHat.

```
cat /proc/version
(Linux version 2.4.21-40.ELsmp (centos@sillage.bis.pasteur.fr) (gcc version 3.2.3 20030502 (Red Hat Linux 3.2.3-53)) #1 SMP Wed Mar 15 13:46:01 EST 2006)
```

Comment: Please clarify: all that exist at all? All that are still developed? All that are installed on the system you're working on?

Comment: All that are installed on the system that I am working on.

Comment: Anyone knows the command on RedHat?

Answer (score 7):

It really depend on your particular distribution or OS.
Say, on debian and ubuntu one uses:

```
$ update-alternatives --list x-window-manager
/usr/bin/twm
/usr/bin/fvwm2
/usr/bin/beryl
/usr/bin/beryl-xgl
/usr/bin/icewm
/usr/bin/kwin
/usr/bin/wmaker
```

Answer (score 5):

A couple more places I found on **Debian**:

```
grep "^Exec" /usr/share/xsessions/*

grep -l "section=.Window Managers." /usr/share/menu/*
```

(In the second, we may want to check the command= part of each file.)

And on an old **Gentoo** I noticed:

```
find /etc/X11/Sessions/* -printf '%f\n'
```

Answer (score 3):

Depends on your distribution/package manager. Most package managers will probably not even have a category "window managers".

Anyway, in gentoo you'd do:

```
$ eix -I -C x11-wm --only-names
x11-wm/enlightenment
x11-wm/twm
```

Answer (score 2):

On Slackware there is nice `xwmconfig`, but I'm not sure if it exists on other distributions.